# How to fill a figure with a certain number of subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello fellow programmers!

I am trying to write code that creates a `matplotlib.pyplot.figure` and fills it with `subplots`. The only input shall be the number of `subplots`. In this case every white box represents one `subplot`.

Following example works for `subplot` numbers that are divisible by 100:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

subplots = 200
cols = int(round(subplots/10))
rows = int(round(subplots/20))

print(f'subplots: {cols*rows}')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols)
_axes = []
for ax_array in axes:
    for ax in ax_array:
        _axes.append(ax)

for ax in _axes:
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)
    ax.plot()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
subplots: 200
```

[image]

This figure is depicted correctly with 200 subplots.

But when I make the change `subplots = 150`, the amount of subplots is calculated and depicted wrong:

```
subplots: 120
```

[image]

How do I compute the correct amount of `nrows` and `ncols` required for depicting the `subplots`? I want the `figure` to be able to depict 149 `subplots` if required.

Is there a better way for doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that you can write `_axes = np.ravel(axes)` (after importing numpy as np) to convert the 2D array of axes into a 1D array. That also works fine even if there only would be one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround using the `modulo` operator and removing excessive subplots afterwards. In this example 149 subplots are to be depicted in a figure with space for 150 subplots. The figure is expanded to the next number divisible by 10 so in this case to 150.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


features = 149
if features % 10 != 0:
    subplots = features + (10-(features % 10))
else:
    subplots = features
print(f'features: {features}')

cols = int(round(subplots/10))
rows = int(round(subplots/cols))
print(f'subplots: {cols*rows}')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols)
_axes = []
for ax_array in axes:
    for ax in ax_array:
        _axes.append(ax)

# axes to be plotted
for ax in _axes:
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)
    ax.plot()

# axes to be removed
for ax in range(10-(features % 10)):
    fig.delaxes(_axes[-(ax+1)])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
features: 149
subplots: 150
```

[image]

Comment: @AndreaBlengino thank you very much for the time you have invested in helping me. I would like to pick your post as the answer for this question but it is has still some cases in which it does not properly depict the subplots. Examples are `subplots = 142` or `143`. In these cases only 141 subplots are depicted.

Comment: @Artur Müller Romanov your answer is very similar to the one I posted before. You can simply turn off some of the plots (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

```
rows = int(round(subplots/20))
```

with this:

```
rows = int(round(subplots/cols))
```

That will fix the the calculated amount of subplots.

---

Since `plt.subplots()` define a rectangular grid of subplots, the total amount of them should not be a prime number, because it must be divisible by the number of columns and the number of rows. If you enter a prime number as `subplots`, you code will find the nearest not-prime number. For example, if you enter:

```
subplots = 149
```

your code will give you `150` subplots, because it does not exist a combination of `cols * rows` which gives `149` as a product.

In order to manage this, use this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

subplots = 149
cols = int(round(subplots/10))
rows = int(round(subplots/cols))

print(f'subplots: {cols*rows}')

if subplots > cols * rows:
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = rows + 1, ncols = cols)
else:
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = rows, ncols = cols)

_axes = []
for ax_array in axes:
    for ax in ax_array:
        _axes.append(ax)

for ax in _axes:
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)
    ax.plot()

if subplots > cols * rows:
    for idx in range(1, cols):
        fig.delaxes(axes[rows, idx])
elif subplots < cols * rows:
    fig.delaxes(axes[rows - 1, cols - 1])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

- in the case when `subplots > rows * cols` (for example `subplots = 31`) it will add a subplot at the bottom:

[image]

- in the case when `subplots < rows * cols` (for example `subplots = 23`) it will delete the last subplot:

[image]

So you can manage all cases.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me fix the first problem. Any idea how to incorporate prime-numbers into my code?

Comment: This is a bad answer, as it will break unexpectedly in many situations. You need `rows = int(math.ceil(subplots/cols))` to make sure all subplots fit. Just leave the last subplots unused, as in general `cols*rows` will be larger then `subplots`.

Comment: This is a bad advice because in the case of `subplots = 31`, `cols*rows` is smaller than `subplots`

Comment: Well, for `subplots = 31`, your code gives `cols = 3`, `rows = 10`. That's why you absolutely need the `ceil` operator that would make `rows = 11`  to fit the last subplot. You can use `....axis('off')` as suggested in the other answer to fully turn off the superfluous subplots.

Comment: Updated answer. Now you can manage all cases by adding o deleting the required difference

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to deal with prime numbers and if having a non-squared grid is an option, you could just define a reference square grid and "turn off" the remaining plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

subplots = 149
cols, rows = 10, 15

nullplots = cols * rows - subplots

print(f'subplots: {subplots}')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols)

# Supress the nullplots
for idx in range(nullplots):
    axes[14, -(idx + 1)].axis('off')

_axes = []
for ax_array in axes:
    for ax in ax_array:
        _axes.append(ax)

for ax in _axes:
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)
    ax.plot()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

In this slight modification of your code I have defined a 10 x 15 square grid that will host 149 plots. Then I remove the `150 - 149 = 1` remaining plots in the right-bottom corner for example. The resulting plot:
[image]

I hope this helps you.